# Crontab not working to send email

Tags: linux, centos, email, cron, shell

I have CentOs 6.5 running on a VPS Host.  I installed crontab and email using the below commands

```
yum install vixie-cron
service start crond
chkconfig crond --levels 235 on

yum install sendmail
service start sendmail
chkconfig sendmail --levels 235 on
```

Now, since I wanted my VPS to send me email, every 5 minutes (for test) about my server status, I [found a script](http://www.tecmint.com/basic-shell-programming-part-ii/) (5th example) that does that, or you can see it below:

```
MAX=95
EMAIL=USER@domain.com
PART=sda1
USE=`df -h |grep $PART | awk '{ print $5 }' | cut -d'%' -f1`
if [ $USE -gt $MAX ]; then
  echo "Percent used: $USE" | mail -s "Running out of disk space" $EMAIL
fi
```

I downloaded the script using curl from [the given URL](http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/scripts/Check-Disk-Space.sh) and modified the EMAIL to reflect my email account.

Now, the last thing I did was, put the above shell script in `/home/user/status.sh` 
and went in to tell cron tab to run it every five minutes.

```
$ crontab -e
*/5 * * * * /home/user/status.sh
```

I assumed this is enough to get the email, but I am not getting any. I have no problems with my email account. What could be the problem?

#### Additional Info:

1. I have root access. Just in case you thought I didn't.
2. And here is my cron log

> [root@user log]# tail /var/log/cron Aug 17 15:15:31 site-name
>   run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[526]: finished makewhatis.cron Aug 17
>   15:15:31 site-name anacron[29624]: Job `cron.daily' terminated Aug 17
>   15:20:01 site-name CROND[622]: (root) CMD (/home/user/status.sh) Aug
>   17 15:25:01 site-name CROND[744]: (root) CMD (/home/user/status.sh)

3. And My maillog
   [image]

Comment: Did you try running the script yourself? What's in the logs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No. I guess I should run it. I have included the logs.

Comment: That's not the _mail_ log!

Comment: Have you tried sending a mail from the command line to verify that your mail is working ?

Comment: Have you also considered the possibility that you aren't running out of disk space? The script won't mail you anything in that case.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I tried to run `bash status.sh` and I get the following error. `status.sh: line 6: [: -gt: unary operator expected` As for the email log, I don't even know what to make of it. Just couple of smileys, that's it..

Comment: I am thinking this error is related to bash. But I have included my maillog too.

Comment: That's not your mail log. Try again :)

Comment: `Aug 17 15:40:10 my-site sendmail[1192]: s7HDe2r7001189: to=<root@my-site.com>, ctladdr=<root@my-site.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:08, xdelay=00:00:08, mailer=local, pri=30947, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent`

Comment: @MichaelHampton It seems it is sent. Sorry for the noobness.

Comment: Progress: When I used `mail -s ...`, I got `-bash: mail: command not found.` but now I installed `yum install mailx` and I am able to send mails directly just fine, but still the cron thing is not workin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the entire script?  There's no 'shebang' line add `#!/bin/bash` to the first line if it isn't there already.  Also did you mark the file executable?

Comment: it actually worked without the sheband. I just had to edit the crontab to `*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/bash /home/user/status.sh`

Comment: That's basically the same thing.  The shebang line and the executable flag allows you to run the script on it's own.  Without it you have to run bash and give the file as input whenever you want to run it.